# How many ints can be stored in the following multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

Having this array:

```
int[][][] x = new int[2][3][2];
```

I thought it was 7, but apparently it's 12. Why is that ?

Comment: Think about the valid index sets...

Comment: They're called multi**dimensional** for a reason.  Think back to geometry, you have a 3-dimensional object, length 2, width 3, height 2; how big is it?

Answer (score 4):

You multiply, not add.  2 arrays with 3 places each, each of which has two places is (2 x 3 x 2 = ) 12.